# how to install lower version of google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

As part of cross browser version testing, I need to test my  application on different chrome browser version. Ex: 50,45,40,30,25 likewise I need to test on 10 different versions.

But I couldn't find portable executable file to install it on my windows 7 32-bit machine.

Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

for example http://google-chrome.software.informer.com/25.0/
(that was the 2. solution on google...)

Comment: download link redirects to the latest version of google chrome installer

Comment: oh okey sorry didnt checked that

Comment: but why u want to test it on 10 different versions?  I would only test it in the current and the oldest of the versions... if it works in the oldest, it surely work in newer ones

Comment: we need to make sure it works for the versions which user did not update it

Comment: as you said you will be testing in oldest versions, how would you do that?

Comment: I am sure that there is a chrome extension